# Parsing JSON after setting Adapter to RecyclerView. Items still displayed

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I don't understand the following.
I create the Adapter before calling parseJSON() and set a new empty ArrayList to it. I don't call notifyDataSetChanged and still the Items are displayed. Why is it not empty?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    parseJSON();
}

private void parseJSON() {
    String url = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key=5303976-fd6581ad4ac165d1b75cc15b3&q=kitten&image_type=photo&pretty=true";

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("hits");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String userName = hit.getString("user");
                            String imageUrl = hit.getString("webformatURL");
                            int likeCount = hit.getInt("likes");

                            mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageUrl, userName, likeCount));
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
}
```

Also where is the appropriate place to set the Adapter here? Should i set it in the parseJSON method directly after parsing the data? Or should i set it like now and then call notifyDataSetChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I create the Adapter before calling parseJSON() and set a new empty ArrayList to it. I don't call notifyDataSetChanged and still the Items are displayed. Why is it not empty?

I don't have your adapter code, so I can't say for sure, but I bet that your adapter and your activity are sharing the reference to `mExampleList`. Imagine your adapter looks like this:

```
public class ExampleAdapter ... {

    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> list;

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExampleItem> list) {
        ...
        this.list = list;
        ...
    }
}
```

When you call `new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList)` and then later add items to `mExampleList`, you will also be adding items to the adapter. If you want your adapter to **not** share the list with whoever passes it in, you should make a copy in your adapter's constructor:

```
this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

> Also where is the appropriate place to set the Adapter here? Should i set it in the parseJSON method directly after parsing the data? Or should i set it like now and then call notifyDataSetChanged?

The way you're assigning the adapter to the recyclerview right now is fine. You can update the backing list after the adpater's been assigned, as long as you notify the adapter of the changes.

### Update

> notice that I don't call notifyDataSetChanged after parsing, that's why I am so confused

If your `JsonObjectRequest` completes fast enough, it won't matter. As long as the list has data at the time the RecyclerView first draws itself, that data will be displayed.

As proof, I wrote this tiny app that creates an empty list of strings, passes that to the adapter, and then updates it afterwards:

```
strings = new ArrayList<>();

RecyclerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
recycler.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(strings));

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        strings.add("Hello");
        strings.add("world!");
    }
}, 30);
```

A 30 millisecond delay is enough to skip at least one frame of drawing, but the RecyclerView still shows my "hello world" message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But notice that I don't call notifyDataSetChanged after parsing, that's why I am so confused.

Comment: @FlorianWalther I updated my answer to address that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I assumed something like that. But i should still notify the adapter after adding, right?
And what do you think about the approach of setting the adapter in the jsonParse method after the parsing is done?

Comment: @FlorianWalther once you've assigned the adapter to the recyclerview, you should always notify it when you change the backing data structure. You're free to set the adapter whenever you'd like, whether in onCreate() or somewhere else; the only real best practice to follow is that it's always more efficient to notify the adapter of changes than to re-set a new adapter to the recyclerview.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were really helpful and quick.